# How much water can you save with self-watering containers?

Tags: watering, container-gardening

I live in a place with very limited water resources, making it difficult to grow food. So I thought I should give self-watering containers a go after reading that they can save a lot of water. But exactly how much can they save? Are we talking about something like 80% or 90%? Or just 50%

Comment: There are a lot of "if this" or "if that" to answer this question. Can you tell us where you are located, daily temperatures, what kind of plants you want to grow? Is the water that is available tap water, well water, rain water....